# sort array using value in particular field

Tags: php, kohana

views.php

```
<?php
    $events = $events->as_array();
    asort($events);
    foreach($events as $event):   
        // some code comes here
    endforeach;
?>
```

Above code is used to sort the array in ascending order.I want to sort the array value in ascending order by referring the value in `from_time` colunm in database,that is the value should order in ascending order with respect to the value in `from_time` column.The above i tried is sorting the value with respect to id.How to sort it with respect to `field(from_time)` in database.

Update:

```
$events = $events->as_array();   

 function cmp(array $a, array $b) {
    if ($a['event_from_time'] < $b['event_from_time']) {//event_from_time is the db column name
        return -1;
    } else if ($a['event_from_time'] > $b['event_from_time']) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

 usort($events, 'cmp');
```

I am getting this error "`ErrorException [ Recoverable Error ]: Argument 1 passed to cmp() must be an array, object given`"  in line "`function cmp(array $a, array $b) {`".

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364127/reference-all-basic-ways-to-sort-arrays-and-data-in-php/17364128#17364128

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $events = $events->as_array();
    foreach($events as $event):
        $res_array[$event->mycat][] = $event->from_time;
    endforeach;
    ksort($res_array);
    print_r($res_array);
?>
```

Comment: It would be useful to provide some explanation of what you are doing. Also, please tidy up your indentation!